# Call SQL Server User-Defined Function (UDF) in Java

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

Is it the same as executing a stored procedure?

Comment: I'll talk for the one who gave you -1 and left... Can you provide more information ? The same on what points ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a SQL function must be referenced with its schema name and must be part of the appropriate part of a SELECT statement. For scalar-valued functions this is something like `SELECT dbo.MyLookupFunction(12)`. For a table-valued function, `SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC FROM dbo.MyTableLookupFunction(12)`. See [CREATE FUNCTION (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Executing User-Defined Functions (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175562%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more information about functions in SQL.

The java code is, of course, the same as for any other query.

Comment: When I try `SELECT dbo.MyLookupFunction(12)`, i get the following exception, `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 1.`

Comment: 12 is just an example, if you're using parameters with your java code try replacing the 12 with ? and execute that. Java's classes for this expect place holders to match the parameters. Parameters in SQL can be expressed in 2 ways, unnamed by using a ?, and named using @parametername.

Comment: I'm using the `?` character, but it's still not working. Is `SELECT dbo.MyLookupFunction(?,?)` valid?

Comment: Add the code you're using to your question. That should be valid.